# How do I let an user input how many times a richtextbox pastes a message?

Tags: c#, forms

I currently have a form where if you type in the Richtextbox it pastes a message 1,000 times. I'm trying to get a form where you can type in a textbox how many times you want the message to be pasted.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox.Text = "Hello world\r\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) richTextBox.Text += richTextBox.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those questions that is so simple, I am not sure I even properly understood your problem.

1. You need a UI Element to type it in. 
   Another textbox works of course. But there also is the [NumericUpDown Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netframework-4.8).
2. You parse the String Input to Integer, unless the control already provide a integer. Use [TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse).
3. You use that parsed number instead of the 10 constant.

As a final note, you should be avoid doing loop opeartions on the Controls. Writing the UI is expensive. If you only do it once per user triggered Event, you will not notice it. But do it in a loop and you will notice it. I even made example code to showcase that:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UIWriteOverhead
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int[] getNumbers(int upperLimit)
        {
            int[] ReturnValue = new int[upperLimit];

            for (int i = 0; i < ReturnValue.Length; i++)
                ReturnValue[i] = i;

            return ReturnValue;
        }

        void printWithBuffer(int[] Values)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            string buffer = "";

            foreach (int Number in Values)
                buffer += Number.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            textBox1.Text = buffer;
        }

        void printDirectly(int[] Values){
            textBox1.Text = "";

            foreach (int Number in Values)
                textBox1.Text += Number.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        private void btnPrintBuffer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Numbers");
            int[] temp = getNumbers(10000);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing with buffer");
            printWithBuffer(temp);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing done");
        }

        private void btnPrintDirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Numbers");
            int[] temp = getNumbers(1000);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing directly");
            printDirectly(temp);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing done");
        }
    }
}
```